# React Native Apollo client.query Not Getting updated data from app sync - dynamo db

Tags: react-native, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, aws-appsync

I use withApollo wrapper to invoke query using `this.props.client.query`. This my code. I have a method and a default wrapper to load start on component mount.
My cache policy for graphql wrapper is `cache-and-network` as app may need to work offline. But when I call the `someMethod` the props must be updated with new data.

```
someMethod = () => {
this.props.client.query({
  query: ListSubjects,
  options: {
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    cachePolicy: { query: true, data: true },
  },
}).then(({ data }) => {
  console.log(data.listSubjects);
  this.props.client.writeQuery({
    query: ListSubjects,
    data,
  });
});
}
......
export default compose (
withApollo,
graphql(ListSubjects, {
options: {
  fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
},
props: props => ({
  subjectList: props.data.listSubjects ? props.data.listSubjects.items : [],
  isLoading: props.data.loading,
  refreshing: props.data.loading,
  loadingStatus: props.data.loading ? I18n.t('loadingText.subjectDetails') : '',
}),
}),
.....
)(Component);
```

When I update the data manual on aws and call query it return cached data and not new data from server. I like to know where I have gone wrong regarding cache policy.

Comment: I too face the same issue. It was returning the new data when updated manually on DynamoDB previously and suddenly it stoped returning the data. If you have found the solution please update the solution for this.